# How to set value of a cell by row and column index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this so far, but it doesn't change the cell value:

```
function setCellValue(tableId, rowId, colNum, newValue)
{
    $('#'+tableId).find('tr#'+rowId).find('td:eq(colNum)').html(newValue);
};
```

Comment: Are you sure your HTML has all of the appropriate `id`'s set?

Comment: Side note - Since `id`s must be unique, you shouldn't have more than one tr with the same id, so you should be able to select the tr by id directly instead of selecting the table first and then the tr.

Comment: Logical flaw, why do `$('#id').find('tr#id')..` when ID's are unique, all you should need is `$('#'+rowId+' td').eq(colNum).html(newValue);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create selector by concatenating index (*in **[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** index starts from `0`*).  Although you need to do the same with row selector since `rowId` is the index of  `tr` not an `id`.

```
function setCellValue(tableId, rowId, colNum, newValue)
{
    $('#'+tableId).find('tr:eq(' + (rowId - 1) + ')').find('td:eq(' + (colNum - 1) + ')').html(newValue);
};
```

---

Or use **[`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** pseudo-class selector.

```
function setCellValue(tableId, rowId, colNum, newValue)
{
    $('#'+tableId).find('tr:nth-child(' + rowId + ')').find('td:nth-child(' + colNum + ')').html(newValue);
};
```

---

Or with single selector by avoiding **[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** method.

```
function setCellValue(tableId, rowId, colNum, newValue)
{
    $('#' + tableId + ' tr:nth-child(' + rowId + ') td:nth-child(' + colNum + ')').html(newValue);
    // or
    $('#' + tableId + ' tr:eq(' + (rowId - 1) + ') td:eq(' + (colNum - 1) + ')').html(newValue);
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when I try `setCellValue("summaryTable",3,3,'100');` nothing happens...

Comment: @LucasSeveryn : can you share the code in snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: @LucasSeveryn : you are missing jQuery library in snippet...... and check it with updated code https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/8k7bqcr8/1/

Comment: @LucasSeveryn : glad to help :)